# Joining two querysets in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following models

```
class Award(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)


class AwardReceived(models.Model):
    award = models.ForeignKey(award)
    date = models.DateField()
    units = models.IntegerField()


class AwardUsed(models.Model):
    award = models.ForeignKey(award)
    date = models.DateField()
    units = models.IntegerField()
```

Now, suppose I want to get the number of awards for all users and the number of awards used for all users (ie, a queryset containing both). I prefer to do it one query for each calculation - when I combined it in my code I had some unexpected results. Also for some of my queries it won't be possible to do it one query, since the query will get too complex - I'm calculating 8 fields. This is how I solved it so far:

```
def get_summary(query_date)
    summary = (Award.objects.filter(awardreceived__date__lte=query_date))
                    .annotate(awarded=Sum('awardissuedactivity__units_awarded')))

    awards_used = (Award.objects.filter(awardused__date__lte=query_date)
                        .annotate(used=Sum('awardused__date__lte__units')))

    award_used_dict = {}
    for award in awards_used:
        award_used_dict[award] = award.used

    for award in summary:
        award.used = award_used_dict.get(award, 0)

    return summary
```

I'm sure there must be a way to solve this without the dictionary approach? For instance, something like this: `awards_used.get(award=award)`, but this causes a db lookup every loop.

Or some other fancy way to join the querysets?

Note this is a simplified example and I know for this example the DB structure can be improved, I'm just trying to illustrate my question.

Comment: What is `exercised_awards_dict` in your exam?

Comment: Sorry, I copied from my code, but didn't change all the variable names - fixed it now

Answer (score 19):

**SOLUTION 1**

Just try to concatenate your queryset using `|`

```
final_q = q1 | q2
```

In your example

```
final_q = summary | awards_used
```

UPDATED:

| does not works using calculated attributes, so, we can select our queryset first and then mapping our extra attributes

```
summary = Award.objects.filter(awardreceived__date__lte=query_date) 
awards_used = Award.objects.filter(awardused__date__lte=query_date)
final_q = summary | awards_used

final_q = final_q.annotate(used=Sum('awardused__date__lte__units')).annotate(awarded=Sum('awardissuedactivity__units_awarded'))
```

**SOLUTION 2**

Using chain built-in function

```
from itertools import chain
final_list = list(chain(summary, awards_used))
```

There is an issue with this approach, you won't get a queryset, you will get a list containing instances.

Comment: If I then use final_q[0].used I get an attribute error. It is as if the calculated value is not included when using |

Comment: Great thanks, I'll it a try. Don't mind getting a list

Comment: is the ordering maintained?

Comment: The point is not to union the querysets, it's to join them right?